# normalize.css and vertical margins for block elements

Tags: html, css, normalize

I am imagining there is a good explanation for this but so far it has more annoyed me than helped. 
Normalize.css adds 1em margins to

elements (and some others). While I see the point from the visual side, it means it often prevents block elements to "touch" each other. I am overriding this at present but would love to understand the reasoning for the vertical margins or if there is a trick I am missing to counteract this side-effect. I am sure some good thinking went into that tweak.

```
p {
    margin: 1em 0; 
}
```

Here is a fiddle reproducing what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/d6njL0zn/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers come standard with 1em vertical margins on elements. That is why Normalize.css also has it. Normalize just takes the normal css defaults in a browser and makes them more consistent across all browsers.

If you would like complete control over how your css is set up, consider using reset.css

Comment: I understand that and in principle it is not a bad idea, however, if you look at the fiddle I created you will see the undesired side effect. The bottom two divs, are rendered without the vertical margins (iow as your browser would naturally).

In my understanding that line of css kind of makes block elements impossible to sit flush under each other. I am now overriding the margin attribute and adding vertical padding instead. hope it does not break something...

Answer (score 0):

HTML2 developed in 1995 had margins for the p and pre tags. The default CSS values are to make those pages which do not use CSS display the same as they did back when they were written. I could be mistaken but I believe the default margin for the body tag of 8 pixels was Microsoft's idea.

Comment: Wayne, I see but am not sure I agree with the normalize approach (unless I am missing something). See my reply to user3123174.

cheers

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the approach taken either. It did not come about as the best solution to web page coding, rather it came about so that pre-CSS pages would continue to function. The problem with the approach is that today and into the future we must continue code in such as way as to support non-existant legacy pages as new pages are created that depend on the default CSS conditions. I hope sometime in the future a new approach is taken, or else we will still be making pages in the year 2095 based on out of the air choices made by Netscape and Internet Explore a hundred years earlier.